# Consecutive statements must be separated by ";" in Swift Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm working in swift and I keep getting the error "Consecutive statements must be separated by ';'" between the two "uids"

```
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let title = postTextField.text
    let content = contentTextField.text

    let postObject = {
        "uid": uid,
        "title": title,
        "content": content
    }
    Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId().setValue(postObject)

    print("Posted to Firebase")
```

Comment: Swift dictionaries use `[]`, not `{}`.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary

Comment: Please read the [Dictionaries](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID113) section of the Swift book.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use curly braces when declaring and initialising a dictionary.
use square brackets.

```
let postObject = [
      "uid": uid,
      "title": title,
      "content": content
    ]
```